# Using separate repo for Ember and backend (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ember.js

I’m going to use separate repos for front-end SAP and Rails. Rails will only serve API. Tests for Ember app will use mocked data.

Up till now I have had Ember app as a subdirectory in Rails app. Using the same repo is easier to maintain. Having a separate repo for backend detaches the two.

Is it worth to keeping them separate? Can deploying be a pain - building from two repos?

App will hosted on Heroku.

Comment: This question is a little too broad for this site. But to point you in the right direction, you'll likely want to add some kind of build step to pull down the other repo and build that as well. I'm not familiar with Ruby's build system (rake?), but I'm sure it can be done. You could also try using [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), as this seems to be what they were designed for.

Comment: @wrynch it would be good to hear what you ended up doing.  I am in a similar position with ember (entire front end) and rails api.  Started with separate repos but am thinking of going with a single repo that has them in completely separate directories.  While linked deployment seems to be both pro and con, the fact that I have access to the model for end to end testing is big.